# While loop stuck

Tags: matlab, while-loop, callback, fwrite, serial-communication

I have written a callback function in Matlab. My laptop is communicating with another laptop that is sending it bytes every few seconds that are recorded in a text file. For e.g. the laptop sends "66" and my laptop writes to the file Event_Markers.txt "66" continuously until the other laptop sends something else. The code is below.

The problem that I am currently facing is that in my callback function (below) I use a `while` loop to continuously write the same "information" (e.g. "66") to the text file until the other laptop sends something else. But this while loop gets stuck. This part is of a larger script that is acquiring data from a spectrometer and adding it to my script and causes everything to become stuck and the rest of the script is not executed. I tried to use an `if` loop instead of `while` and it only writes "66" twice instead of writing it continuously. It is, however, writing to the text file as I want it to.

Does anybody know if I need to add some other line of code to stop it becoming stuck?

Thanks!

```
appenderFile=fopen('Event_Markers.txt','a+t');
s=serial('COM3');
set(s,'BytesAvailable',{@myCallback,appenderFile});
set(s,'BytesAvailableFcnCount',1);
set(s,'BytesAvailableFcnMode','byte');
fopen(s);

function myCallback(s,~,appenderFile)
    bytes=(s,'BytesAvailable')

    if(bytes==1)
         [data count msg] = fread(s,bytes);
    end 

    fprintf(appenderFile,'%d \n',data);
    bytes=(s,'BytesAvailable');

    while bytes==0
         fprintf(appenderFile,'%d \n',data);
         bytes=get(s,'BytesAvailable');
    end
end
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could display receive bytes on command window to make sure you are getting expected information or not.

Comment: I am not familiar with serial communication in matlab but do you not required to read the serial port again and again inside the while loop.

Comment: @User1551892 thats what the callback function does, it continuously reads.

Comment: @User1551892 I have previously displayed and it is receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break out of the loop when "something else is sent", something like:

```
while bytes==0
   fprintf(appenderFile,'%d \n',data);
   bytes=get(s,'BytesAvailable');
   if s ~= 66
     break
   end
 end
```

Comment: I tried adding in this `break` but it has the same effect as the `if` loop, it only records "66" twice instead of continuously...